# Custom component Ionic3 + Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've created a custom component and add it to a components.module.ts file.

I've a folder in my project called components with the components.module.ts file inside.

This how my components.module.ts file looks:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import { SendMessageBoxComponent } from './send-message-box/send-message-box.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SendMessageBoxComponent
  ],
  imports: [IonicModule],
  exports: [
    SendMessageBoxComponent
  ]
})

export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Then I want to use this component in a page (chatpage), this is how the chat.module.ts file looks:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ChatPage } from './chat';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChatPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ChatPage),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ChatPage
  ],
})
export class ChatPageModule {}
```

This is my chat.module.ts page:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ChatPage } from './chat';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChatPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ChatPage),
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ChatPage
  ],
})
export class ChatPageModule {}
```

And this is the chat.ts file code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
})
export class ChatPage {
  user: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewWillLoad(){
    this.user = this.navParams.get('data');
  }

}
```

Im getting the:

Template parse errors: 'app-send-message-box' is not a known element

What Am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: where are you using chatPageModule?post that code too

Comment: Can you show your `chatpage` component please?

Comment: If you dynamically load SendMessageBoxComponent then you will need to add it in module's entryComponents.

Comment: Question updated. Thanks guys!

Comment: I've fixed it following Jose F. Rodriguez's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966337/inject-custom-component-in-ionic-3-page